# Error in finding the frequency of an Input square wave signal

Tags: timer, arduino, interrupt

Is there any way to calculate the frequency of input square wave signal on a digital pin? or should I be completely relied upon the [pulseIn()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/pulsein/) function??

I have written the `ISR` of my code like this

```
ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect){
  count++;
}
ISR(TIMER1_CAPT_vect){
  value = TCNT1;
  TCNT1 = load;
  }
```

and tried to print the values on serial monitor(variables: `value` and `load` are `volatile` variables) but it shows zeroes only. I cant figure out whats going wrong in it.!

The declaration of the program is as follows

```
const uint16_t freqPin = PD5;
const uint16_t load = 0;
volatile unsigned long int count=0;
volatile unsigned int value=0;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
DDRD &= ~(1<<freqPin);
TCCR1A = 0;
TCCR1B &= B11111000 | B00000111;
TCNT1 = load;
TIMSK1 |= (1<<ICIE1);
TIMSK1 |= (1<<TOIE1);
TIFR1 |= (1<<TOV1);
sei();
}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the line `TCCR1B &= B11111000 | B00000111;` you are not configuring correctly the register. It's seem like you want to configure to B11111111, but as you don't know the value in it, it can be anything, including 0, what makes the timer stop.

Change this line to `TCCR1B = B11111000 | B00000111;`, but be aware because with this configuration you'll need a external clock source for the timer, so I advice you to use another value for the last three bytes